# Obtener valores los valores de un enum e iterar en java

Tags: java, arraylist, color, enum

A ver si me podéis echar una mano, tengo una clase tipo enum con colores y su código de color, y necesito que devuelva el código hexadecimal del enum, que en caso de no existir devuelva el valor NO_DEFINIDO.

```java
public enum Color {
    AMARILLO ("#FFFF00"),
    ROJO("#FF0000"),
    VERDE("#00FF00"),
    AZUL("#0000FF"),
    GRIS("#888888"),
    NEGRO("#000000"),
    NARANJA("#FF8300"),
    NO_DEFINIDO ("#")
    ;

    private String codigo;
    private Color(String codigo) {
        this.codigo= codigo;
    }
public String getCodigoHex() {

        return code; //Esto devuelve el codigo hexadecimal del color
    }

public Color getColor(String code) {

//Metodo que devuelve el codigo de color hexadecimal y que en el caso de que no exista de vuelve no definido
}
}
```

¿como podria hacer el metodo getColor()???

Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Obtener valores los valores de un enum e iterar en java

Cada vez que definimos un `enum`, podemos hacer uso del método estático [values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)). Esta rutina devuelve todas las constantes del `enum` y a través de un bucle se puede ir obteniendo la constante de forma separada.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
enum Color 
{
    AMARILLO ("#FFFF00"),
    ROJO("#FF0000"),
    VERDE("#00FF00"),
    AZUL("#0000FF"),
    GRIS("#888888"),
    NEGRO("#000000"),
    NARANJA("#FF8300"),
    NO_DEFINIDO ("#")
    ;

    private String codigo;
    private Color(String codigo) 
    {
        this.codigo= codigo;
    }
    public String getCodigoHex() 
    {
        return codigo; 
    }

    public Color getColor(String code)
    {
        for(Color col : values())
        {
            if(col.getCodigoHex().equals(code))
                return col;
        }
        return NO_DEFINIDO;
    }
}
```

Forma de uso:

```java
class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        String code = "#00FF00";
        String code2 = "00FF00";
        System.out.println(Color.NO_DEFINIDO.getColor(code));
        System.out.println(Color.NO_DEFINIDO.getColor(code2));
    }
}
```

Resultado por pantalla:

```java
VERDE
NO_DEFINIDO
```

Comment: muchas gracias MrDave!